# Removing vtkBoxWidget from an volume

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, mfc, vtk

I am struggling for weeks to a simple matter: to remove vtkBoxWidget from an volume, on loading another volume inside of vtk window ...
I take it from [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Widgets/BoxWidget) an example of how to use an vtkBoxWidget. Everything run ok. I clip some part from loaded volume.

The problem begin when I am trying to load another volume. I disabled the box widget, I even remove it:

```
    if(m_pBox->GetEnabled())
        m_pBox->Off();
    m_pBox->SetDefaultRenderer(NULL);
    m_pBox->RemoveAllObservers();
    m_pBox->SetInteractor(NULL);
    m_pBox->Modified();
```

after that, I loaded the new volume. In vain, the new loaded volume is already clipped with the last state ... why ? How can I get rid of from the vtkBoxWidget, in order that new loaded volume being complete (I mean not clipped) ?

In other words, how can I reunify the volume, after I clipped with vtkBoxWidget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
m_pVolumeMapper->RemoveAllClippingPlanes();
```

the mapper of the volume should be clean up from all clipping planes. In case that someone need it.